# DatePicker bug on Oreo: year selector not scrolling when System Setting = Display Size Large

Tags: android, datepicker

I found a terrible bug in my app after upgrading to Oreo 8.0.
In the System Settings I set "Display Size = Large.
[image]
After that I noticed that the Datepickers in my apps would not allow me to scroll the year. It would only let me select the visible years 2016 - 2022. (when starting with year 2018).

[image]

If I set the System setting back to normal, all is fine.
I now know this to be an Android Bug, since the Google own calendar App has the same problem.

---

I searched the internet, but didn't find good work-arounds. Does anybody here know of the problem and have a work-around?

Comment: Found any solution? It also happens with default settings on device and using SDK 29. It's a PITA to enter 1970 using steps of 2 years

Comment: Problem seems to be solved when switching "Display size" to small and back to default...